# Rails 4 - exporting routes to CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing an ecommerce app and I have a csv export feature which exports all product details like name, price, etc. Each product is in one row with a column for each product attribute. I want to add a column to the file which will contain the url of each product. The reason I want this is so I can use this as a product feed that can be submitted to various shopping sites.

Here is my export code in the controller.  How do I add a column called route to this? I don't have a route column in the model.

```
 #controller
 def productlist
  @listings = Listing.all

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.csv { send_data @listings.to_csv(@listings) }  
   end
 end

 #model
    def self.to_csv(listings)
  wanted_columns = [:sku, :name, :designer_or_brand, :description, :price, :saleprice, :inventory, :category]

  CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << ['Product_ID', 'Product_title', 'Designer_or_Brand', 'Description', 'Price', 'SalePrice', 'Quantity_in_stock', 'Category'] + [:Image, :Image2, :Image3, :Image4]

    listings.each do |listing|
      attrs = listing.attributes.with_indifferent_access.values_at(*wanted_columns)
      attrs.push(listing.image.url, listing.image2.try(:url), listing.image3.try(:url), listing.image4.try(:url)) 

      csv << attrs

    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def self.to_csv(listings)

  wanted_columns = [:sku, :name, :designer_or_brand, :description, :price, 
    :saleprice, :inventory, :category]
  header = %w(Product_ID Product_title Designer_or_Brand Description Price 
      SalePrice Quantity_in_stock Category Image Image2 Image3 Image4 ProductUrl)

  CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << header

    listings.each do |listing|
      attrs = listing.attributes.with_indifferent_access.values_at(*wanted_columns)
        << listing.image.url << listing.image2.try(:url) 
        << listing.image3.try(:url) << listing.image4.try(:url)
        << Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.product_url(listing.Product_ID)
      csv << attrs
    end
  end
end
```

Actually the only difference is last item of array: `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.product_url(listing.Product_ID)`, where `product_url` is your route to `product#show`

Comment: On the url line, I get an error saying `Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true`.

Comment: How do you perform it, from console?

Comment: No, I click on the export button on localhost. I tried setting the `:only_path => true` option. When I do that, the export runs without error but the url column in csv is blank.

Comment: Well, you have two choices: 1. specify `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = host` for each environment, cause models do not have access to the request context and do not know anything about host. 2. Move `to_csv` logic into some helper, where you have access to the request.

Comment: Will try specifying host when I get back online. But I tried listing_path instead so the host would not be needed but still no luck...the file exports with url as blank.